# java servlet repeat post

Tags: java, servlets, repeat

I want to make java servlet make something like while-do condition based on input. Assume I make it to receive input named UserInput and post output named ProgramOutput continuously, something like chatting with the program. This is my doPost code:

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String UserInput= request.getParameter("UserInput").toString();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title></title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    while (true){
    out.println(UserInput+ "<br>"); //this is the place where user type his/her words
    out.println("<input type='submit' value='submit'>");
    request.getParameter("UserInput").toString();
        if ("stop".equals(UserInput)) //unless user type 'stop', program will keep printing the answer
        break;
    String ProgramOutput= engine.answer(UserInput); //from engine.java
    out.println(ProgramOutput+"<br>");}
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.close();
```

When I tried to run it, it never stopped printing the same input and output without even give user to type another words and checked it. What should I do?

Sorry, this is my first time making servlet, if possible I want an easy-to-understand answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing VIEW and CONTROLLER in the same code. This is not a good approach. 
Ideally you should have one jsp (VIEW) for providing user input and on submit of that page call a servlet(CONTROLLER) which will process request and return control back to jsp so that user can provide inputs.

Will suggest you to read MVC framework.